# Programmatically upload a file to a custom file field

Tags: files

I am trying to update a node and programmatically upload a file.

```
$nid = 45343;
$node = node_load($nid);

$image_url = 'http://test.com/misc/druplicon.png';
$file = system_retrieve_file($image_url, file_default_scheme().'://products_images/'.basename($image_url), TRUE);

// We save the file to the root of the files directory.
// $file = file_copy($file, 'public://');

$node->field_custom_file[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = (array)$file;
node_save($node);
```

Somehow, it's not working at all. Do I need to add more functions to it?

Comment: It looks right, but where are you running that code from?

Comment: I am testing it in running it in the page.tpl.php

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me.

```
$image_url = 'http://test.com/misc/druplicon.png';    
$file_info = system_retrieve_file($image_url, 'public://documents/', TRUE);

if ($file_info->fid) {
  $node->field_custom_file['und'][0]['fid'] = $file_info->fid;
}

$node_ready = node_submit($node);
node_save($node_ready);
```